# React Native ActivityIndicator not displaying

Tags: android, react-native, activity-indicator

Packages that am using:

```
"@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^2.6.0",
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.2.0",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^8.2.0",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.8.5",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.0",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.7.0",
"date-fns": "^2.14.0",
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
"react-native-razorpay": "^2.1.35",
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.1",
"react-native-screens": "^2.9.0",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^7.0.0"
```

And my `ActivityIndicator` is placed inside a screen component like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native'
   

export default function Loading({navigation}) {
       
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image
                style={styles.main_logo}
                source={require('../assets/logo.png')}
            />
            <Text style={styles.loading_text}>...Loading...</Text>
            <ActivityIndicator animating={true} size="large" style={{opacity:1}}  />
            
        </View>
    )
    
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  },

  main_logo : {
    width: 100,
    height: 53,
    marginBottom: 20
  },

  loading_text : {
      color: 'white'
  },

  
})
```

The problem is, it doesn't show the `ActivityIndicator`. Everything else is appearing. Tested both in real mobile device (Redmi Note 7 Pro) and Android Emulator. Seems to be transparent.

Any fix for this?

Comment: You'll have to show more than that

Comment: @D10S, I have edited. Please check

Comment: "It doesn't show anything" - do you see the <Text> component?

Comment: @Dan Only the ActivityIndicator is not appearing. Everything else is appearing as expected.

Comment: Try to change it to <ActivityIndicator size="large" />

Comment: @D10S no luck. I actually added it without any parameters and since it was not appearing, I googled and found I have to pass the `animating` explicitly. That's why I tried that parameter too. But no luck

Comment: no need to pass animation as it is default (exactly like 'opactiy:1'). Try to remove the text and image check if still nothing.

Comment: @D10S When I removed the image and text, the screen is empty. Just the background color.

Comment: Sorry but it's out of my knowledge spectrum. Good luck Vpp man.

Answer (score 118):

Be sure to give the `ActivityIndicator` a color. For example:

```
<ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
```

Comment: That is absolutely ridiculous, this property does not have a default value...

Comment: I believe it defaults to grey. I guess it could just be bad luck if you are trying to display it on a grey background like I just did. Still, I think the docs should include the color prop in the example.

Answer (score 30):

On react-native 0.63.3 exist bug, on android without color prop
[Default color for ActivityIndicator on Android #30057](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/30057/files)

Answer (score 8):

From React Native version 0.63 onwards there is an Android specific bug(https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/30057/files) with ActivityIndicator component which is causing the default color of ActivityIndicator to be null and so the component won’t be displayed on the screen. But in IOS platform GREY is passed as the default color and it works fine there.

So for Android, currently we have to explicitly add the color to the ActivityIndicator using the color property(https://reactnative.dev/docs/activityindicator#color) as below. Also if you want to keep your app consistent across platforms this property will ensure that the same color is displayed for the ActivityIndicator in both Android & IOS platforms.

```
<ActivityIndicator animating={true} size="large" style={{opacity:1}} color="#999999" />
```

Answer (score 6):

My workaround to force default color value for Android somewhere in your root component. Like

```
import { ActivityIndicator, Platform } from "react-native";

// fix https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30056
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {  
  if (!ActivityIndicator.defaultProps) ActivityIndicator.defaultProps = {};
  ActivityIndicator.defaultProps.color =  'gray';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Modal,
    ActivityIndicator
} from 'react-native';

const Loader = props => {
    const {
        loading,
        ...attributes
    } = props;

    return (
        <Modal
            transparent={true}
            animationType={'none'}
            visible={loading}
            onRequestClose={() => {console.log('close modal')}}>
            <View style={styles.modalBackground}>
                <View style={styles.activityIndicatorWrapper}>
                    <ActivityIndicator
                        animating={loading} />
                </View>
            </View>
        </Modal>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    modalBackground: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
        backgroundColor: '#00000040'
    },
    activityIndicatorWrapper: {
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
        borderRadius: 10,
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-around'
    }
});

export default Loader;
```

and call this component like this

```
<Loader loading={this.state.isLoading} />
```

this.state.isLoading could be either true or false

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue (rendering the ActivityIndicator inside a modal) that wasn't resolved with setting the colour prop. However the ActivityIndicator component provided by react-native-paper worked as expected, follow the getting started instuction and then just drop it in place of the standard react-native one. See: https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/activity-indicator.html.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Android. Solved like this: I centered the ActivityIndicator in a View. Before it was on top left corner and not shown. Here is the code:`
<View

```
        style={{
            flex: 1,
            opacity: 1,
            backgroundColor: "wheat",
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
        }}>
        <ActivityIndicator
            animating={true}
            size='large'
            style={{ opacity: 1 }}
            color='brown'
        />
    </View>`
```